# DataTables - Using aoColumnDefs throws an error

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using datatables jQuery Plugin numeric-comma and want to sort by numeric comma values.

When i try to follow the method advised by datatables i got an error

Error: k[(qa ? qa : "string") + "-" + h[c][1]] is not a function

Here is my code given below

```
var oTable = $('#transactiontable').dataTable( {
                "iDisplayLength": 10,
                "aLengthMenu": [[10, 20, 50, -1], [10, 20, 50, "All"]],
                "bProcessing": true,
                /*"bServerSide": true,*/
                "oLanguage": {
                    "sEmptyTable": "There is no transaction found.",
                    "sSearch": "Search all columns except few:"
                },
                "sAjaxSource": "transactions-processing.php",
                "sScrollX": "100%",
                "sScrollXInner": "3000px",
                "bScrollCollapse": true,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "aoColumnDefs": [
                    {
                        "bSortable": false,
                        "aTargets": [ 18,19,20,21,22 ]
                    },
                    {
                        "sType": "numeric-comma",
                        "aTargets": [ 3 ]
                    }
                ],
                /*"fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aaData, iDisplayIndex ) {
                    if ( aaData[1] == "5" ){
                        $('td:eq(1)', nRow).addClass( 'testrow' );
                    }
                },*/
                "fnInitComplete": function () {
                    new FixedColumns( oTable, {
                        "iLeftColumns": 2,
                        "iRightColumns": 1
                    });
                }
            });
            <?php }?>
        });
```

Can somebody check my code and guide me where i am wrong...?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

If you run your table through the DataTables debugger ( http://debug.datatables.net/ ) that might give us a clue as to what is happening. What is the error you get if you use the unminified version of DataTables?

Comment: Here is the link of my uploaded debug code (http://debug.datatables.net/ekadup). Now will you please help me out to sort out my issue.

Comment: I have fixed the issue sir. Thank you very much. But i am stuck into other problem. My sorting feature is not working on my live server where as it is working perfectly fine at my local machine. Can you please also guide me that why this is happening? This is my updated uploaded debug code (http://debug.datatables.net/arutev). It works fine locally but does not working on remote server.